# How can I combine the three queries to one and possibly improve performance

Tags: sql

I wish I can get help from this forum, any suggestion is appreciated.

I have a project with some existing sql queries, here are three I think should be combined into only one for the performance optimization purpose.

For the sake of simplicity and confidentiality here are the modified codes:

1. `table1` inner join `table2` **and left join `table22`** to generate `temp` table
2. from `temp` table create table `cnt` with the count for each type
3. `table1` inner join `table3`, and apply a `where` clause to generate the final table
   .

**UPDATE: the key point here is to look for a solution that can minimize the initial data volumn (`table1`) involved here - which has 8 billion rows, from the `where` clause added at the end it should be able to restricted to the `where` clause which will dramatically bring down the size.**

**UPDATE2: the original queries actually include another left join here, please see the comment below:**
[image]

```
 create table table1 (id int, region int, typeid int)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (1,2,1)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (2,3,1)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (3,4,2)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (4,1,2)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (5,1,2)
 insert into table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (6,2,4)

 create table table2 (id int, type varchar(10))
 insert into table2 (id, type) values (1,'A')
 insert into table2 (id, type) values (2,'B')
 insert into table2 (id, type) values (3,'C')
 insert into table2 (id, type) values (4,'D')
```

table `temp` is the initial inner join of the two initial tables:

```
create table temp as
select a.*, b.*
from table1 a  inner join table2 b on a.typeid = b.id
```

table `cnt` has the count for each type

```
create table cnt as
select c.type, count(1) as total
from temp c
group by type
```

Final table:

```
create table final as
select a.region, a.type
from table1 a  inner join cnt c on a.type = c.type  where c.total > 2
```

In the given sample data, the final table should contains only records with `type = 2` because `type2` has `count > 2`

Kindly keep in mind the current `table1` and `table2` contain millions of rows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have appropriate indexes on your large tables, doing this in steps may not be necessary. Depending on your database, a lot of your 'delcarative' code might be unnecessary because the query planner is smart enough to do it for you

Comment: Thanks Nick, we have partitions, index is not applicable to my case.

Comment: Indexes are always applicable for database performance

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTEs.  So one simplification is:

```
with cnt as (
      select ?.type, count(*) as total
      from table1 a inner join
           table2 b
           on a.typeid = b.id
      group by a.type
select a.region, a.type
from table1 a inner join
     cnt c
     on a.type = c.type
where c.total > 2;
```

`table2` doesn't contribute to the count, so this can be simplified to:

```
with cnt as (
      select ?.typeid, count(*) as total
      from table1 a 
      group by a.typeid
select a.region, a.typeid
from table1 a inner join
     cnt c
     on a.typeid = c.typeid
where c.total > 2;
```

And if your window functions further simplifies this:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by a.typeid) as cnt
      from table1 a
     ) a
where cnt > 2;
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think the final query is correct: table temp is the initial inner join of the two initial tables and table cnt needs to be derived from table temp, your final query doesn't do that.

Comment: @mdivk . . . The `join` is not needed as I read the queries.  It is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks Gordan. without join, how do I filter the table with where clause that the count is needed and the count is from the join?

Comment: @mdivk . . . The count on `typeid` without the `join` should be the same as the count on `type` with the `join`.

Comment: the count would be different (I apologize I should include another left join in my simplified query here)

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster i believe if you have partition over typeid of table 1:

```
create table #table1 (id int, region int, typeid int)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (1,2,1)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (2,3,1)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (3,4,2)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (4,1,2)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (5,1,2)
    insert into #table1 (id, region, typeid ) values (6,2,4)

--exact your request:
select t.region, t.typeid from #table1 t where t.typeid in (select t.typeid from #table1 t group by t.typeid having count(t.typeid) > 2)
--...and if you need group:
select t.region, t.typeid, count(*)recordcount from #table1 t where t.typeid in (select t.typeid from #table1 t group by t.typeid having count(t.typeid) > 2) group by t.region, t.typeid 

drop table #table1
```

Comment: Thank you, partition is on a different field.

Comment: you can still try the query

Comment: Thanks, suspended it here for now, the real script is too complex and too big